# how to align 2nd column in align environment?

Tags: align, amsmath

This:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    s_yp&=s_zp                  &&  \Longleftrightarrow\\
    S_yp &= S_zp                    &&  \Longleftrightarrow\\
    S_y\left(\sum_{x}a_x\delta_x\right) &=S_z\left(\sum_{x}a_x\delta_x\right)   &&  \overset{Z\text{-Linearität}}{\Longleftrightarrow}\\
    \sum_{x}a_x\left(S_y\delta_x\right)&=
    \sum_{x}a_x\left(S_z\delta_x\right)&&   \Longleftrightarrow\\
    \sum_{x}a_x\left(S_z\delta_x\right.&-\left.S_y\delta_x\right)=0 &&  \Longleftrightarrow\\
    \sum_{x}a_x\left(S_z\right.&-\left.S_y\right)\delta_x = 0
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Produces that:

[image]

How can I make the arrows line up ignoring the overset?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apply a `\mathclap` to the text (`mathtools` required).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    s_yp&=s_zp                  &&  \Longleftrightarrow\\
    S_yp &= S_zp                    &&  \Longleftrightarrow\\
    S_y\left(\sum_{x}a_x\delta_x\right) &=S_z\left(\sum_{x}a_x\delta_x\right)   &&  \overset{\mathclap{Z\text{-Linearität}}}{\Longleftrightarrow}\\
    \sum_{x}a_x\left(S_y\delta_x\right)&=
    \sum_{x}a_x\left(S_z\delta_x\right)&&   \Longleftrightarrow\\
    \sum_{x}a_x\left(S_z\delta_x\right.&-\left.S_y\delta_x\right)=0 &&  \Longleftrightarrow\\
    \sum_{x}a_x\left(S_z\right.&-\left.S_y\right)\delta_x = 0
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using a directive such as `\makebox[0pt][c]{...}` to contain the first argument of `\overset` (or, use `\mathclap`), you should (a) get rid of all `\left` and `\right` parenthesis-sizing directives -- use `\biggl(` and `\biggr)` for the four large parentheses in the third row -- and (b) align all equations on their respective `=` symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' environment
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
s_yp &= s_zp       &&  \Longleftrightarrow\\
S_yp &= S_zp       &&  \Longleftrightarrow\\
S_y\biggl(\sum_{x}a_x\delta_x\biggr)  
     &=S_z\biggl(\sum_{x}a_x\delta_x\biggr)   
     &&  \overset{\text{\makebox[0pt][c]{$Z$-Linearität}}}{\Longleftrightarrow}\\
\sum_{x}a_x(S_y\delta_x) 
     &= \sum_{x}a_x(S_z\delta_x)
     &&   \Longleftrightarrow\\
\sum_{x}a_x(S_z\delta_x - S_y\delta_x) &= 0 
     &&  \Longleftrightarrow\\
\sum_{x}a_x(S_z- S_y)\delta_x          &= 0
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```